# Finding palindromes and the longest word in a string

Tags: javascript, strings, palindrome

I have two little projects that I've been working on.

One is to find all palindromes:

```
function palindrome(str) {
  var replaceStrChr = str.replace(/\W/g,'').replace(/ /g,'').replace(/_/g,'').toLowerCase();
  var arrayifyStr = replaceStrChr.split('').reverse();
  var stringifyStr = arrayifyStr.join('');

  if (replaceStrChr === stringifyStr){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And the other one is to find the longest word in a string:

```
function findLongestWord(str){
    var arrayify = str.split(' ');
    var longest = 0;

    for(var x = 0; x < arrayify.length; x++){
        if (arrayify[x].length > longest){
            longest = arrayify[x].length;
        }
    }
    return longest;
}
```

What I'm looking for is a better way to do these, shortcuts, better syntax, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the palindrome:

- You can probably just use one `replace` operation, but with a more extensive regex. My regex is rusty but something like `/[\W_\s]/g` could do.
- `split`, `reverse` and `join` could possibly be just one chain.

  ```
  var reversedString = replaceStrChr.split('').reverse().join('');
  ```
- Comparisons are essentially boolean values. You can simply do:

  ```
  return replaceStrChr === stringifyStr;
  ```

For the longest word:

- Use `reduce` and carry through the longest word.

  ```
  var longestWord = str.split(' ').reduce(function(prev, next){
    return next.length > prev.length ? next : prev;
  });
  ```
- `str` doesn't tell me what the string contains. Only when I saw `split(' ')` did I realize it was a space-separated string. Rename the variable to show its purpose.

Comment: `length > prev.length ? next : prev;` ternary?

Comment: @13aal Yes, that's a ternary.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the examples and the advice.

Answer (score 1):

I pretty much second everything in @Joseph the Dreamer's answer except for simplifying the palindrome.

You can simplify the regex by making it just `/[\W_]/g`. So, we now can get the reduced string. We do not need to check for white spaces since those are non-word characters (`\W`).

```
replaceStrChr = str.replace(/[\W_]/g, '');
```

Then there is no need to reverse the string then compare them. We can save time by checking it at the same time:

```
for(var i = 0, j = replaceStrChr.length; i < j;)
    if(replaceStrChr[i++] !== replaceStrChr[j--]) return false;
return true;
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's a really good idea, thanks for this